# Codeigniter PostgreSQL error connecting database

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I'm used to Codeigniter with mysql(i) but I have a customer who needs PostgreSQL to be connected. I tried the usual settings and added the specific port for Postgre but I get this error:

`Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.`

[image]

My code is simply this:

```
$active_group = (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') ? 'offline' : 'online';
//Set to 'development' in file: index.php    
$active_record = TRUE;

/**
 * OFFLINE CONFIGURATION
 */

$db['offline']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['offline']['username'] = 'root';
$db['offline']['password'] = 'root';
$db['offline']['database'] = 'testing';
$db['offline']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['offline']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['offline']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['offline']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['offline']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['offline']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['offline']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['offline']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['offline']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['offline']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['offline']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['offline']['port'] = 5432;

/**
 * ONLINE CONFIGURATION
 */
$db['online']['hostname'] = '?';
$db['online']['username'] = '?';
$db['online']['password'] = '?';
$db['online']['database' .... 
//Continues with online configuration...
```

Now I'm using the `offline` configuration for now and this is not working showing the error above. I did try to set "db_debug" to FALSE and that works but I feel like is just skimping the point and I'll never get database error shown which I need in offline mode...

I have [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) open and is connected to the same database and is working ok. Any hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

IF there is problem with

```
$db['offline']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre'
```

then use

```
$db['offline']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo'
```

instead of postgres.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html) for the CodeIgniter DB drivers, the available values are `mysql, postgres, odbc`. So, change the `$db['offline']['dbdriver']` value from `postgre` to `postgres` and try again. It should connect without problems as long as your username and password are right.

**Edit:** There are other sources which suggest that the driver name is actually `postgre` instead of `postgres`, contrary to the documentation (that's a shame, really). So I'd suggest that you try with `postgres` and `postgresql`. If it's still not working, check your php.ini, and check if you have uncommented the PostgreSQL module (search for `extension=php_pgsql` line).

The module is called `php_pgsql.so` on Linux boxes, and `php_pgsql.dll` on Windows.

If you see it and it has `;` before the line, remove the `;` and restart the Apache server (it should be available on Windows). If not, you need to install it first and then add it to php.ini. The installation varies from distro to distro, but there are plenty of tutorials on how to install it on a Linux box.

Comment: Tku. I did try but that's not working. Error:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(.../system/database/drivers/postgres/postgres_driver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: database/DB.php

Line Number: 140

Looks like is actually `postgre` and not `postgres` from here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/131807/#925186

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking there was an error in the username.
The configuration was not done by me and the person writing the original username put `postres`instead of `root` as was agreed.

Unfortunately the CI class doesn't output that specific error but just a general "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."

Sorry for the post. Thanks to everybody.